# Can i call a member function of a class using integer pointer in c++

Tags: c++

```
class ABC // class ABC
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        cout <<"hi";
    }
};

int main() //main method
{
    ABC d;//object of class ABC
    int *p=reinterpret_cast<int*>(&d);
     p->f();// trying to call function f by taking address of object
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've cast a pointer to ABC to an `int*`, this won't compile as `int` has no method `f()`

Comment: What did your compiler say when you tried this?

Comment: @qrkv Scalar type int is not a class type. So it does not have member functions. This statement p->f(); is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking raw data literally, without considering symmetric of language.

Compiler will allow,(though logically it may be incorrect)

```
int *p=reinterpret_cast<int*>(&d);
```

But it will not find any `f()` for int.

So `p->f();` will definitely give compiler error.